# Calculating the cumulative distribution function and the probability density function of an interval with ratio of a shorter and longer segment

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, stochastic-processes

The interval $[0, 2]$ is divided into two parts by randomly marking a point in $[0, 1]$ according to the rectangular distribution. Let $X$ be the length ratio $L_1/L_2$ of the shorter segment $L_1$ to the longer segment $L_2$. Thus, $L_1$ is in the interval $[0, 1]$, and $L_2$ is greater than or equal to $1$, and also it is in the interval $[0, 2]$.
First calculate the cumulative distribution function then calculate the probability density function $f_X(x)$ of $X$.

Does somebody have some tips for me on how to even tackle this problem? I dont expect a solution just a way to atleast calculate the cumulative distribution function. For clarification its a university homework above our level and we are allowed to use external resources. I just need some help on how to even start, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work too well to tell us you just want guidance; to receive a good answer; and then to *change your question* to inquire whether your work is correct.  That looks merely like you're trying to use this site to do and check your homework.

Comment: I used the help to come up with an answer and just wanted to see if i have done it the correct way. Im sorry if i used this platform the wrong way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$L_1$ follows a Uniform $(0,1)$ and $L_2 = 2-L_1$.
So
$$X = \frac{L_1}{L_2} = \frac{L_1}{2-L_1}.$$

Use this, together with the definition of the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$, that for some value $x$
$$F_X(x) = \Pr(X\leq x).$$

**Note:** inside the probability, things can move around as long as, in the end, you keep the random variable(s) to the left of the inequality, and the fixed quantities to the right. Once you have a single random variable to the left of the inequality, then you have the cumulative distribution function of *that* variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the help. I updated my question with the current solution. If you have time i would be happy for you to review it.

Comment: @Ste0l Apart from our moderator intervention, the solution involves very basic mathematical operations, like differentiation. You should feel confident in doing them, since they do  not involve anymore anything from probability theory itself.